# Windows Community Toolkit IoC :: Is it || Will it be capable to add IoC Modules by other vendors or its own ones?

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject, windows-community-toolkit, dryioc

Is [Windows Community Toolkit IoC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/ioc) anyhow capable to receive pre-configured modules by `NInject`, for example ?

`DryIoC` is having modules on its [roadmap](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/issues/326) so maybe that will become also neat so that we can deploy the dependency configurations to the Unit Tests.

Anyhow possible to achieve this with the Community Toolkit IoC or is there an existing plan on any1's desk ?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. You mean using the Ninject module registrations with DryIoc without dependency on Ninject?

Comment: Hi @dadhi, I was asking whether the **Windows Community Toolkit** `IoC` is capable or will be capable to receive modules by other vendors. Or maybe does it have its own modules concept, so that I can configure a single module once and use it in multiple assemblies (e.g. in Unit Tests) ?

Comment: Ok, by module do you mean this kind of thing  https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/FaqAutofacMigration.md#modules ?

Comment: Exactly, one can leverage the registrations at arbitrary places and maintain in a single place only.